# How to create and consume ROWTYPE in PL/SQL andJava

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I have created a function in PL/SQL like below:

```
create or replace function test_sp_get_user_detail
(u_id in varchar2)
return user_details%rowtype
as

l_user_record user_details%rowtype;
begin
select * into l_user_record from user_details
where user_id = u_id;
return(l_user_record);
end;
```

I refer that if I want to consume this function at Java I need to create a type as well in PL/SQL, I have a doubt here that whether am I right or wrong if I am right how to create a type and what is the type I have to give in register out parameter in callable statement in Java, or if I am wrong.

How to consume in Java? Can anybody please tell me how can I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

A `rowtype` can be *consumed* in Java as you would any other row returned from a simple `SELECT` query:

You can get a `ResultSet` and from that call `next()` and `getXX()`

```
ResultSet rs = ...
while(rs.next()) {
    String myString = rs.getString(1);
    String myString2 = rs.getString("returned_column_name");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your replace. but i am asking before resultset logic.ie. cst.registerOutParameter(1,"what type i have to user here",typeTableName);
      cst.setString(2,"some input")
   cst.execute();